# Table pull to refresh not working

Tags: ios

when i refresh the table then its is no refresh and not show the circle  on the screen .
This is my code:-

```
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];

[self.tableHolidays addSubview:refreshControl];

[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)refreshTable {
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.tableHolidays reloadData];
}
```

Comment: [UIRefreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/)

Comment: try endRefreshing after reloadData.   [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

Comment: @Suhailkalathil it doesnt matter, the matter is the code in the `refreshTable`  func, that code he provide doesnt do anything at all, no circle can be magically appear when call that 2 lines, atleast have to give that drawing or something code

Comment: is your tableview is samller  than it's frame ... ?(i mean number of rows)

Comment: @Tj3n.. what about this    ..  self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {
   
    [self downloadFeed];
}  -(void)downloadFeed{ [self.tableView reloadData];[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];}

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/22060573/5362916

Answer (score 1):

Try interchanging the sequence

```
- (void)refreshTable {

    [self.tableHolidays reloadData];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
    // Do your stuff here, when done:
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First complete all operations on Table while refreshing & then end refreshing.

`- (void)refreshTable {
    [self.tableHolidays reloadData];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}`